# cp: cannot overwrite directory with non-directory

Tags: linux, file-transfer

Running the copy command as `sudo cp -v -r -f source destination`, for few directories and files, getting error as `cp: cannot overwrite directory with non-directory`.

Comment: The error message seems quite clear. Can you describe your problem in more detail?

Answer (score 7):

**CASE 1** You get this error when you try to copy a file (source) that has the same name of a directory (destination).

**CASE 2** You get this error when you try to copy a symlink (source) in a directory (destination) where there is already an object with the same name.

**SOLUTIONS**

Use [rsync](https://linux.die.net/man/1/rsync). See also the following options about symlinks

> -l, --links                 copy symlinks as symlinks
>
> -L, --copy-links            transform symlink into referent file/dir
>
> --copy-unsafe-links     only "unsafe" symlinks are transformed
>
> --safe-links            ignore symlinks that point outside the tree
>
> -k, --copy-dirlinks         transform symlink to dir into referent dir
>
> -K, --keep-dirlinks         treat symlinked dir on receiver as dir

Otherwise: manually remove the object from destination path (or move, or rename), then copy the object from the source path.

Answer (score 0):

Probably, the destination name has different type.
Like:
You want to copy `source` to `destination`, but where you want to copy `source` has already `destination.bin` or `destination.vim` or `destination.txt`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).